# Struggling to create raycast suspension in Godot 4

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

The code I have currently makes the car jump around a few times then hit the ground and not push the car back up.
[Hopping car](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gU6Id.gif)
I have commented the first wheel code to explain what the suspension is doing each line.
This is the code I'm using. I'm expecting it the car to land and damper the landing, not to bounce around as it does.

```
# vehicle.gd
extends RigidBody3D

# Suspension variables
@export var suspension_rest_length: float = 0.5 
@export var suspension_max_length: float = 1.0
@export var suspension_stiffness: float = 500.0
@export var dampening_sensitivity: float = 450.0
@export var dampening_max: float = 30.0

# Suspension Raycasts
@onready var fr: RayCast3D = $FR
@onready var fl: RayCast3D = $FL
@onready var rr: RayCast3D = $RR
@onready var rl: RayCast3D = $RL

# Wheel nodes
@onready var fr_wheel: Marker3D = $FR/Wheel
@onready var fl_wheel: Marker3D = $FL/Wheel
@onready var rr_wheel: Marker3D = $RR/Wheel
@onready var rl_wheel: Marker3D = $RL/Wheel

func _physics_process(delta):
    if fr.is_colliding():
        # Get distance to ground
        var dist = fr.get_collision_point().distance_to(fr.global_transform.origin)

        # Get dampening, clamp between 0 and max dampening
        var dampening = clamp(fr_wheel.get_velocity().length() * dampening_sensitivity, 0, dampening_max)

        # At location of raycast, apply suspension forces
        self.apply_force(fr.global_transform.basis.y * (suspension_stiffness * (dist - suspension_rest_length) + dampening))

        # Set location of wheel to raycast collision point
        fr_wheel.global_transform.origin = fr.get_collision_point()
   
    if fl.is_colliding():
        var dist = fl.get_collision_point().distance_to(fl.global_transform.origin)
        var dampening = clamp(fl_wheel.get_velocity().length() * dampening_sensitivity, 0, dampening_max)
        self.apply_force(fl.global_transform.basis.y * (suspension_stiffness * (dist - suspension_rest_length) + dampening))
        fl_wheel.global_transform.origin = fl.get_collision_point()
  
    if rr.is_colliding():
        var dist = rr.get_collision_point().distance_to(rr.global_transform.origin)
        var dampening = clamp(rr_wheel.get_velocity().length() * dampening_sensitivity, 0, dampening_max)
        self.apply_force(rr.global_transform.basis.y * (suspension_stiffness * (dist - suspension_rest_length) + dampening))
        rr_wheel.global_transform.origin = rr.get_collision_point()
  
    if rl.is_colliding():
        var dist = rl.get_collision_point().distance_to(rl.global_transform.origin)
        var dampening = clamp(rl_wheel.get_velocity().length() * dampening_sensitivity, 0, dampening_max)
        self.apply_force(rl.global_transform.basis.y * (suspension_stiffness * (dist - suspension_rest_length) + dampening))
        rl_wheel.global_transform.origin = rl.get_collision_point()
```

Comment: The only thing I notice is that the force applied is central, not at the location of the raycast as the comment says, since you are not using the second parameter of the method.

Comment: @Theraot I have rewritten it like this, but it still jumps around:
self.apply_force(Vector3.UP * (suspension_stiffness * (dist - suspension_rest_length) + dampening), fr.global_transform.basis.y)